# Appengine Python memcache capacity shrunk

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

After uploading a app new version appengine, `memcache` reduced in size. When I log the `memcache statistics`(memcache.get_stats())`, I see that the oldest_item_age is less the a minute old and the cache size is not more then 3 meg. In the older version of the app, the oldest_item 3600 second old and the cache size was ~30 meg. 
I work with backends and when I stop them the problem disappear.
also I use django-nonrel
Thanks

Uri

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the backends actually affect memcache capacity, but I do know that it's variable and changes over time. It might also be a shared pool of some sort, and might also vary depending on which of your instances the request happens to hit. It could have also been because you'd just pushed a new version.

I usually don't worry about check the capacity. To reduce server load, it's in the GAE team's own best interests to apply the best optimization, allocation and eviction policies to your memcache.

Comment: strictly speaking the GAE team's best interests also include making money.  memcache is free, datastore queries are (presumably) a profit center.  (I am not suggesting they are shrinking memcache for this purpose, just being cynical and pointing out that Google's interests are not strictly the same as ours.)

Comment: That's what I used to think too... but then they're encouraging everyone to use as much caching as possible, and the upcoming datastore library has automatic caching. Think they really want to cut down on Bigtable activity and make money on the instance uptime charges, and the datastore writes.