# How to retrieve huge (>2000) amount of entities from GAE datastore in under 1 second?

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-bigquery

We have some part of our application that need to load a large set of data (>2000 entities) and perform computation on this set. The size of each entity is approximately 5 KB.

On our initial, naïve, implementation, the bottleneck seems to be the time required to load all the entities (**~40 seconds for 2000 entities**), while the time required to perform the computation itself is very small (<1 second).

We had tried several strategies to speed up the entities retrieval:

> - Splitting the retrieval request into several parallel instances and then merging the result: **~20 seconds for 2000 entities**.
> - Storing the entities at an in-memory cache placed on a resident backend: **~5 seconds for 2000 entities**.

The computation needs to be dynamically computed, so doing a precomputation at write time and storing the result does not work in our case.

We are hoping to be able to retrieve ~2000 entities in just under one second. Is this within the capability of GAE/J? Any other strategies that we might be able to implement for this kind of retrieval?

UPDATE: Supplying additional information about our use case and parallelization result:

> - We have more than 200.000 entities of the same kind in the datastore and the operation is retrieval-only.
> - We experimented with 10 parallel worker instances, and a typical result that we obtained could be seen in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Ug2uVGH3). It seems that the serialization and deserialization required when transferring the entities back to the master instance hampers the performance.

UPDATE 2: Giving an example of what we are trying to do:

> 1. Let's say that we have a StockDerivative entity that need to be analyzed to know whether it's a good investment or not.
> 2. The analysis performed requires complex computations based on many factors both external (e.g. user's preference, market condition) and internal (i.e. from the entity's properties), and would output a single "investment score" value.
> 3. The user could request the derivatives to be sorted based on its investment score and ask to be presented with N-number of highest-scored derivatives.

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve so many entities for a user-facing request? Can you give more details as to what you're actually doing?

Comment: We need to present the user a subset of entities that gives the largest profit based on some input parameters and a user-defined function. In our use case, we are only able to reduce the search space to a subset of ~2000 entities at best.

Comment: As Peter points out, you're trying to retrieve a gig of data for a single user query. You need to restructure this in some way, and without more information about what you're doing, it's difficult to say how.

Comment: Well, not really a gig, I think it's more like ~10 MB. (Or did I misunderstood the way the datastore works?) Is 10 MB/s throughput from the datastore something out of reach at the time being? I had updated the question with an example of what we tried to do.

Comment: sounds like a MapReduce problem.

Comment: It's not 10MB/s - it's 10MB/s per page request. That's going to add up fast if you have more than a couple of users. You need to restructure.

Comment: @NickJohnson Restructuring imperative aside, so 10MB/s throughput is beyond the datastore's capability at the moment? Some type of applications would inevitably need to do a large-scale data analysis requiring that kind of throughput, no matter how cleverly we structure it. It would be great if Google could publish read throughput data for the datastore similar to the one shown in the memcache system status: http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/memcache/2012/01/19#ae-trust-detail-memcache-get-multi-throughput

Comment: @IbrahimArief The issue constraining you here is latency more than throughput. The amount of data you can retrieve in a given time from a single process does not represent the total throughput of the datastore, because it's a distributed, parallel bit of infrastructure. Large scale data analysis is done by parallelizing.

Comment: I think this is a perfect use case for BigQuery. You can stream your Datastore entries into BigQuery and do your computation using ~SQL and the BigQuery statistical functions. Your performance requirement is not an issue in that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it does not appear that we could retrieve >2000 entities from a single instance in under one second, so we are forced to use in-memory caching placed on our backend instance, as described in the original question. If someone comes up with a better answer, or if we found a better strategy/implementation for this problem, I would change or update the accepted answer.

Comment: This was long time ago and the GAE has improved a lot since then. Did you find any better solution for this since then? We just hit the same read performance bottleneck.

Comment: @shelll Unfortunately, the company where I worked this issue at that time has moved away from GAE, and now I've moved to another company that does not do any dev in GAE, so I do not know the best practice solution for this issue at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

200.000 by 5kb is 1GB. You *could* keep all this in memory on the [largest](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html#Billing_Quotas_and_Limits) backend instance or have multiple instances. This would be *the fastest* solution - nothing beats memory.

Do you need the whole 5kb of each entity for computation?
Do you need all 200k entities when querying before computation? Do queries touch all entities?

Also, check out [BigQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/bigquery/). It might suit your needs.

Comment: That would be highly optimistic. :) 5KB is the size of the serialized entity, the deflated object would took several times that amount in memory. Based on our tests, we estimate that a B8 backend with 1GB memory could cache about 40k entities. Retrieving ~2000 entities from the in-memory cache is very fast (~500 ms), but sending the result from the cache backend to the requesting instance took several seconds. We only need several properties of the entity, our initial query had reduced the number of loaded entities from 200k to ~2k, and the query is applied to all entities of the kind.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Memcache](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/memcache/). I cannot guarantee that it will be sufficient, but if it isn't you probably have to move to another platform.

Comment: Looking at the app engine status page, memcache multi-get has ~60 MB/s throughput, and could conceivably load 2000 entities @ 5KB well under a second. But there's already another part of our application that intensively use memcache, and we're worried that this would cause huge miss-rate since cache eviction would be frequent.

Comment: I'm not sure what the cache quotas are (haven't been able to find a definitive number), but since the maximum entity size is 1 MB I'm guessing it's much larger than 10 MB; the max size for a fetch is 32 MB too. Given these numbers I find it unlikely that it's sized at less than 64 MB (to be *very* conservative), likely many times that.

Comment: Since the statistics in the quota details panel for data sent and retrieved are in gigabytes, I'm guessing that eviction would not be a problem for this scale of data.

Comment: That is a good thought, and I think Memcache provides a getStatistics() method to query the total bytes stored in all the keys and values in the Memcache. I'll write a simple test to know what the real limits are in my app, but from what I read in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633792/appengine-python-memcache-capacity-shrunk , the limits could change without warning.

Comment: That must have been a pretty particular case (barring any error in usage or in getStatistics()), I can't imagine the cache being normally < 10 MB; I mean, with 250 byte keys!

Comment: A quick test, which are still running up to this moment on my backend server, seems to point that the limitations is size-based rather than based on the number of entries. The memcache on my app right now contains ~24000 entries @ 1KB, and containing ~40 MB worth of data, and still no sign of eviction.

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting, but yes, its possible & Iv seen some mind boggling results.

I would have done the same; map-reduce concept

It would be great if you would provide us more metrics on how many parallel instances do you use & what are the results of each instance?

Also, our process includes retrieval alone or retrieval & storing ?

How many elements do you have in your data store? 4000? 10000? Reason is because you could cache it up from the previous request.

regards

Comment: Updated question with more information. Could you share an example of the mind boggling results that you had seen?

Answer (score 0):

Our solution involves periodically reading entities in a background task and storing the result in a json blob. That way we can quickly return more than 100k rows. All filtering and sorting is done in javascript using SlickGrid's DataView model.

As someone has already commented, MapReduce is the way to go on GAE. Unfortunately the Java library for MapReduce is broken for me so we're using non optimal task to do all the reading but we're planning to get MapReduce going in the near future (and/or the Pipeline API).

Mind that, last time I checked, the Blobstore wasn't returning gzipped entities > 1MB so at the moment we're loading the content from a compressed entity and expanding it into memory, that way the final payload gets gzipped. I don't like that, it introduces latency, I hope they fix issues with GZIP soon!